# How do I get rid of this text above my toolbar?

Tags: python, system

I'm not sure what key I accidentally hit, but now I have this text above my toolbar (the one with "file, render, window, help" on it). Please refer to the attached image so that you can see what I'm talking about.

Googling yielded no results so that's why I'm here. How do I get rid of it?

Thanks,
HS

[image]

Comment: Grab the edge up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just pull up the info window...

Place the cursor at the line where the 3D window and the Info window meet. The cursor should change to a double arrow.

Pull the info window up.

[image]

Note, both above and below that header you get a "double arrow":

you don't have to drag the *upper* separation line

[image]

but the *bottom* line as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it should be pretty simple and I've been trying to do that, but it just won't work? I'll try again, but if it doesn't work is there potential that my copy is buggy? My computer also has a hard time running blender sometimes. Could that be it?

Comment: Tried again and it just won't pull up. :/

Comment: @user50531 : the upper window has a header with the file/render/window/help menu and a "double arrow" is shown both above and below it. You need to use the _bottom_ separation line (eg: _below_ the menu words and it should move while using the _above_ does not -  that line may be used to collapse the header).

Comment: I see! I'm pretty new to all computer programs so I'm really ignorant. Thank you!